# Centering a Div shape within another Div

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to set up 4 divs side by side, within each of these is a smaller div hexagon shape which I would like to centre within the first div. The shape inside is a little complicated as its made up of a couple of divs creating a hexagon shape. I cant seem to get this shape in its entirety to move away from the edge.

I'm using zurb foundation framework
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks
Ant

http://codepen.io/Hornetant/pen/akrgaN?editors=1010

```css
#one {
  height: 500px;
  background-color: red;
  float: left;
  padding: 0px;
}
#two {
  height: 500px;
  background-color: blue;
  float: left;
  padding: 0px;
}
#three {
  height: 500px;
  background-color: green;
  float: left;
  padding: 0px;
}
#four {
  height: 500px;
  background-color: orange;
  float: left;
  padding: 0px;
}
.hextext {
  padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: 'Droid Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
.hexagongreen {
  position: relative;
  width: 150px;
  background-color: #1aa07d;
  margin-top: 60px;
}
.hexagongreen:before,
.hexagongreen:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  border-left: 75px solid transparent;
  border-right: 75px solid transparent;
}
.hexagongreen:before {
  bottom: 100%;
  border-bottom: 40px solid #1aa07d;
}
.hexagongreen:after {
  top: 100%;
  width: 0;
  border-top: 40px solid #1aa07d;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="medium-3 columns" id="one">
    <div class="hexagongreen">
      <div class="hextext"><b>DID YOU KNOW?</b>
        <br>Hayfever affects 15 million people in the UK
        <br>each year</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="medium-3 columns" id="two">
    <div class="hexagongreen">
      <div class="hextext"><b>DID YOU KNOW?</b>
        <br>Hayfever affects 15 million people in the UK
        <br>each year</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="medium-3 columns" id="three">
    <div class="hexagongreen">
      <div class="hextext"><b>DID YOU KNOW?</b>
        <br>Hayfever affects 15 million people in the UK
        <br>each year</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="medium-3 columns" id="four">
    <div class="hexagongreen">
      <div class="hextext"><b>DID YOU KNOW?</b>
        <br>Hayfever affects 15 million people in the UK
        <br>each year</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: for inner div use margin: 0 auto;

Answer (score 0):

Clear the float on your hexagon text and center with margin auto on the left and right, like so:

```
.hextext{
  padding:10px 20px 10px 20px;
  color:#ffffff;
  font-family: 'Droid Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  float: none;
}



.hexagongreen {
  position: relative;
  width: 150px; 
  background-color: #1aa07d;
  margin-top:60px; 
  margin: 60px auto 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `margin: 60px auto;`. The `auto` value for left/right margin horizontally centers the hexagon. See the example below (in fullscreen mode).

Also see [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_align.asp) for some examples of alignment with CSS or [CSS-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/) for a centering guide.

```css
.columns {
  float: left;
  padding: 0px;
  height: 500px;
  width: 25%;
}
#one {
  background-color: red;
}
#two {
  background-color: blue;
}
#three {
  background-color: green;
}
#four {
  background-color: orange;
}
.hextext {
  padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: 'Droid Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
.hexagongreen {
  position: relative;
  width: 150px;
  background-color: #1aa07d;
  margin: 60px auto;
}
.hexagongreen:before,
.hexagongreen:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  border-left: 75px solid transparent;
  border-right: 75px solid transparent;
}
.hexagongreen:before {
  bottom: 100%;
  border-bottom: 40px solid #1aa07d;
}
.hexagongreen:after {
  top: 100%;
  width: 0;
  border-top: 40px solid #1aa07d;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="medium-3 columns" id="one">
    <div class="hexagongreen">
      <div class="hextext"><b>DID YOU KNOW?</b>
        <br>Hayfever affects 15 million people in the UK
        <br>each year</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="medium-3 columns" id="two">
    <div class="hexagongreen">
      <div class="hextext"><b>DID YOU KNOW?</b>
        <br>Hayfever affects 15 million people in the UK
        <br>each year</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="medium-3 columns" id="three">
    <div class="hexagongreen">
      <div class="hextext"><b>DID YOU KNOW?</b>
        <br>Hayfever affects 15 million people in the UK
        <br>each year</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="medium-3 columns" id="four">
    <div class="hexagongreen">
      <div class="hextext"><b>DID YOU KNOW?</b>
        <br>Hayfever affects 15 million people in the UK
        <br>each year</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a container around the hex box and set the width to 100% and then add margin: 50% auto; to the hex box itself.  You can see a working example in the CodePen.io example I have linked.

HTML

```
     <div class="medium-3 columns"  id="one"> 
       <div class="hexagon-container">
           <div class="hexagongreen hexagon-center">
               <div class="hextext"><b>DID YOU KNOW?</b><br>Hayfever affects 15 million people in the UK <br>each year</div>
           </div>
       </div>
     </div>
```

CSS

```
.hexagon-container {
  width: 100%;
}

.hexagon-center {
  margin: 50% auto;
}
```

[CodePen Example](http://codepen.io/NosNits/pen/OXGLLP)

Answer (score 0):

here is the code to centre an element within another:

```
/* center positioning */
/* first, you need a wrapper for that element to center it vertically within your parrent element */
.centered-wrapper{
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    transform:translateY(-50%);
    z-index:1;
    width:100%;
}
/* this is the element to be centered, here you are centering it horizontally */
.centered{
    margin:0 auto;
    float:none;
    padding-left:5%; /* you might not need this padding, it depends on how the rest of your css is set up */
}
```

the `.centered` element also needs a fixed width (by fixed I mean any kind of set width, `px`, `%`, whatever)
that's it, hope it helps.

here's an example on plunkr as well:
https://plnkr.co/edit/a0lruDZV1OpvsAtjaOEQ?p=preview

here's the solution for your exact problem, run this in your codepen and see if it's what you're looking for:

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="medium-3 columns"  id="one"> 
    <div class="centered-wrapper">
      <div class="hexagongreen centered">
        <div class="hextext"><b>DID YOU KNOW?</b><br>Hayfever affects 15 million people in the UK <br>each year</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


<div class="medium-3 columns" id="two">
  <div class="centered-wrapper">
    <div class="hexagongreen centered">
      <div class="hextext"><b>DID YOU KNOW?</b><br>Hayfever affects 15 million people in the UK <br>each year</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="medium-3 columns" id="three">
  <div class="centered-wrapper">
    <div class="hexagongreen centered">
      <div class="hextext"><b>DID YOU KNOW?</b><br>Hayfever affects 15 million people in the UK <br>each year</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="medium-3 columns" id="four">
  <div class="centered-wrapper">
    <div class="hexagongreen centered">
      <div class="hextext"><b>DID YOU KNOW?</b><br>Hayfever affects 15 million people in the UK <br>each year</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.columns{
  position:relative;
}

.centered-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-68%);
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
}


/* this is the element to be centered, here you are centering it horizontally */

.centered {
  margin: 0 auto;
  float: none;
  background-color: green; /* i have collored the divs to make it more clear what it's happening */
}
#one{
  height:500px;
  background-color:red;
float:left;
  padding:0px;
}
#two{
height:500px;
  background-color:blue;
 float:left;
  padding:0px;
}
#three{
height:500px;
  background-color:green;
float:left;
  padding:0px;
}
#four{
 height:500px;
  background-color:orange;
   float:left;
  padding:0px;
}

.hextext{
  padding:10px 20px 10px 20px;
  color:#ffffff;
 font-family: 'Droid Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.hexagongreen {
  position: relative;
  width: 150px; 
  background-color: #1aa07d;
margin-top:60px; 
}

.hexagongreen:before,
.hexagongreen:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  border-left: 75px solid transparent;
  border-right: 75px solid transparent;
}

.hexagongreen:before {
  bottom: 100%;
  border-bottom: 40px solid #1aa07d; 
}

.hexagongreen:after {
  top: 100%;
  width: 0;
  border-top: 40px solid #1aa07d; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.hexagongreen{
  margin: 60px auto;
}
```

```css
#one{
  height:500px;
  background-color:red;
float:left;
  padding:0px;
}
#two{
height:500px;
  background-color:blue;
 float:left;
  padding:0px;
}
#three{
height:500px;
  background-color:green;
float:left;
  padding:0px;
}
#four{
 height:500px;
  background-color:orange;
   float:left;
  padding:0px;
}

.hextext{
  padding:10px 20px 10px 20px;
  color:#ffffff;
 font-family: 'Droid Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.hexagongreen {
  position: relative;
  width: 150px; 
  background-color: #1aa07d;
margin-top:60px; 
}

.hexagongreen:before,
.hexagongreen:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  border-left: 75px solid transparent;
  border-right: 75px solid transparent;
}

.hexagongreen:before {
  bottom: 100%;
  border-bottom: 40px solid #1aa07d; 
}

.hexagongreen:after {
  top: 100%;
  width: 0;
  border-top: 40px solid #1aa07d; 
}
```

```html
   <div class="row">
     <div class="medium-3 columns"  id="one"> 
       <div class="hexagongreen">
    <div class="hextext"><b>DID YOU KNOW?</b><br>Hayfever affects 15 million people in the UK <br>each year</div></div></div>


<div class="medium-3 columns" id="two">   <div class="hexagongreen">
    <div class="hextext"><b>DID YOU KNOW?</b><br>Hayfever affects 15 million people in the UK <br>each year</div></div></div>
<div class="medium-3 columns" id="three">   <div class="hexagongreen">
    <div class="hextext"><b>DID YOU KNOW?</b><br>Hayfever affects 15 million people in the UK <br>each year</div></div></div>
<div class="medium-3 columns" id="four">   <div class="hexagongreen">
    <div class="hextext"><b>DID YOU KNOW?</b><br>Hayfever affects 15 million people in the UK <br>each year</div></div></div>
</div>
```